# Crossdomain issue when loading video thumbnails (Flash)

Tags: flash, facebook-graph-api, video, thumbnails, cross-domain-policy

I'm trying to display some Facebook video thumbnails in a Flash application, all of the video thumbnails i try to load seem to be hosted at https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net.

However [crossdomain.xml](https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml) cannot be loaded (Access Denied). Is there some way around this? (other than loading the images through a proxy). Maybe an alternative url which can be used?

edit: This is a Facebook bug and [has been reported](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/270901383004607)

Comment: It's probably a great reason to [file a bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) (or add details to [one existing for photos](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318962154792404))

Comment: It seems like thats the only way to go. I've posted it as [a new bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/270901383004607) since the bug you mentioned is different (and solved).You should have posted this as an answer as it turns out to be an actual bug so filing a bug report is the only proper solution.

Comment: Actually posting this as an answer would be wrong, since it's not answering the question but just a suggestion (which is more suitable as comment) and don't really add any value to community aside of knowledge that this may be a bug... It'll be great if you'll update your question with link to bug you created, so other users will be able to subscribe to it as well ;) BTW, the bug I've refered is in reopen-ed state so you can add "additional info" to it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a proxy to load the thumbs through so crossdomain was no issue, i've just checked and the crossdomain files are correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a LoaderContext in your Loader and set the checkPolicyFile flag to true:

```
var lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
lc.checkPolicyFile = true;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("https://url.com/image/path/name.jpg"), lc);
```

Comment: The issue is not that the loader does not try to load the Policy file, the issue is that the file just doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues with crossdomain policy files on Akamai CDNs. Here's an in depth look at a similar problem to yours, and a solution:

http://jessewarden.com/2009/03/handling-crossdomainxml-and-302-redirects-using-netstream.html

Comment: An interesting read but sadly not exactly the same issue, i do get 302 redirected to a new location, but when i try to load the crossdomain of the new location i get an error because the actual file location has no crossdomain.xml